# Request for Explanation

Tags: c#

Working on some exercises from my C# Programming 3E book (By Barbara Doyle) and the question asks

> Explain the relationship between System, Console, and Read

The my solution was: it uses input/output. But I'm not really sure if it's correct which is why I'm asking for assistance.

Comment: I downvoted because both the title and question body is grammatically incoherent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer should be something alone the lines of:

> 'System is the namespace.  Console is a class contained within the
>   System namespace.  Read is a method on the Console class.'
>
> Namespace -> Class -> Method

But I might be wrong :)

Comment: I think it is what is asked. =)